# Correctly Initializing the Physics State Outside of SimpleApplication

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

So I've been learning how to use the jme3 engine and SDK. I started toying around with working outside of the main application file that extends SimpleApplication to further objet-orient my application.

My question is this.. How do I correctly initialize the physics object? As in.. You create a Player class that has a BulletAppState object named phyiscs, but is not assigned a value AT FIRST! It is assigned within the constructor.

```
class Player {
     BulletAppState physics;

     public Player(BulletAppState physicsState) {
          this.physics = physicsState; // State should now be initialized when 
                                       // this constructor is is called
     }
}
```

Then, in the main class file

```
class Main extends SimpleApplcation {

     Player player;
     BulletAppState physics;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Main app = new Main();
          app.start();
     }

     @Override
     public void simpleInitApp() {
          physics = new BulletAppState();
          physics.setThreadingType(BulletAppState.ThreadingType.PARALLEL);
          stateManager.attach(physics);

          player = new Player(); 
     }
}
```

I do not get the desired result that I expect.

The output results are:

Main class physics state enabled? True

Player class physics state enabled? False

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `physics` in your `Player()` constructor to initialize `BulletAppState` like this.

```
player = new Player(physics);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo on my end. I was passing the physics object in the constructor. But when I use physics.isEnabled(); it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Big hint:  stateManager.attach() adds the thing to a Queue!

The only appStates that are initialized during the call to simpleInitApp are those passed into the constructor at `new Main(appStates...)`

I've got this working well in my object-oriented game project:

`Main app = new Main( new StatsAppState(), new FlyCamAppState(), new DebugKeysAppState(), physics );`

And it passes nicely to all objects in the simpleInitApp() call.